# spring-social-github can't get user email

Tags: spring, github-api, spring-social

I'm using spring-social/spring-social-github in order to authenticate user through GitHub in my Spring Boot web application.

In order to sign in user I have created following html form:

```
<form action="http://example.com/auth/github" method="POST">
 <input name="scope" value="user,gist" type="hidden">
 <button type="submit">Sign in with GitHub</button>
</form>
```

everything works fine except I can't get user email address.

According to GitHub documentation [GitHub OAuth API](https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/#scopes) `user` scope includes `user:email` and `user:follow`.

What can be wrong ?

**UPDATED**

After talking with GitHub support I have more information on this one:

The problem is that this library uses following https://api.github.com/user endpoint in order to get user profile. That endpoint returns the public email address for the user, and users don't need to specify a public email address. So, if the user doesn't have a public email address defined -- you get a null value back.

The https://api.github.com/user/emails endpoint returns the private list of email addresses and that list should always have at least one address.

if it possible to extend spring-social-github library in order to call https://api.github.com/user/emails endpoint for user email address ?

Right now I'm unable to override `GitHubTemplate.initSubApis()` in order to initialize my own version of `UserTemplate.getUserProfile()` because `GitHub Template.initSubApis` is a private method..

I have created issue on GitHub for [spring-social-github can't get user email](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-social-github/issues/29)

Comment: Did you try just `user:email`? What are you able to access from the API after connection is established from the profile?

Comment: the same thing.. only first name as a "null" string value and that's all

Comment: Can you check through curl what scopes you have using the token, there's a code on the API page under scopes section.

Comment: X-OAuth-Scopes: user:email

Comment: The same result with: X-OAuth-Scopes: gist, user

Comment: I can only get username from github

Comment: That's strange, you should contact githubs support on that matter https://github.com/contact

Comment: yeah.. thanks. Submitted question to GitHub support.

Comment: I got some information from GitHub support. Updated question body